# accessing classpath from tomcat to dynamically compile code snippets

Tags: tomcat, servlets, javac

I have java code snippets dynamically generated which refer back to classes with public apis in the tomcat classpath.  I am able to correctly identify the public apis (methods) of these classes thru reflection, but then after using this information to generate my java code I was to compile it with the Java Compiler API.

Is this possible?  Do I need to get the classpath that tomcat has used to load my servlet somehow and pass it to the Java Compiler API?

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass the classpath.. This code does the classpath retrieve stuff

```
List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
options.add("-classpath");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
for (URL url : urlClassLoader.getURLs()){
    sb.append(url.getFile().replace("%20", " ")).append(File.pathSeparator);
}
options.add(sb.toString());
```

You pass the options to the compiler.getTask

CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(writer, memoryManager, diagnostics, **options**, classes, compilationUnits);